# d.b calls structure - new to d.b

Tags: python, sqlite

i have a question about building calls to d.b (mysql lite)

i have a d.b table with many URL's
in my code i scrape few more links from a specific website.

i want to check if the URL's i scraped are in my d.b or not.

what should i do? get a list of all the existing URL's in the d.b and check if the new urls are in that list or check the new URL's 1 by 1 if they exist in d.b?

what is the correct approach?

this is what im currently doing:

```
     # get the links of quotes in the page above
quotes = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='entry-title']/a")]

# open the quotes d.b
conn = sqlite3.connect('quotes.db')
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT quote from QUOTES")

# make a list of all quote in d.b
all_quotes = []
for row in cursor:
    all_quotes.append(''.join(row))

#   check each quote from thai tours page if its not in the d.b - if not add to list
new_quotes = []
for quote in quotes:
    if quote not in all_quotes:
        new_quotes.append(quote)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a collection of values and you want to find whether they exist in a table you can use a `WHERE` clause, like this:

```sql
SELECT some_column FROM my_table WHERE some_column IN ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

In Python, we need to build the placeholders for the `IN` part, so we would do something like this:

```py
quotes = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2[@class='entry-title']/a")]

# Make a placeholder ("?") for each quote
placeholders = ','.join(['?'] * len(quotes))

# Add the placeholders to a query
stmt = """SELECT quote FROM quotes WHERE quote IN ({})""".format(placeholders)

# Execute the query
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(stmt, quotes)
rows = cursor.fetchall()

# Each row is a tuple, so extract the first element
matches = [row[0] for row in rows]

# If a quote isn't in matches it's new
new_quotes = [quote for quote in quotes if quote not in matches]
```

Doing the above identifies the quotes that don't already exist in the database.  However if the purpose of identifying new quotes is to insert them into the database, we can take a shortcut: Sqlite** supports an [INSERT OR IGNORE](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) syntax which will ignore errors if we try to enter duplicate values.  For this to work, we need the values in the `quote` column to be unique, if they aren't already.

We can force `quote` to be unique by adding a unique index with this SQL:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_quote ON quotes (quote);
```

Once the index is present, quotes can be inserted directly:

```
cursor.executemany("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO quotes (quote) VALUES (?)""", quotes)
```

---

* This syntax is not standard SQL, so it will not work with other database engines, although some database engines provide something similar.